# Show that this Neumann problem has a unique solution

Tags: vector-analysis, poissons-equation

> Let $\rho(\mathbf x)$ be a function on a volume $V$ and $f(\mathbf x)$
>    a function on its boundary $S=\partial V$. Show that a solution $\phi
>  (\mathbf x)$ to the following problem is unique: $\nabla^2 \phi
>  -\phi=\rho$ on $V$ , $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}=f$ on $S$.

I would usually put my thought so far, but I have none.

Of course, anything is appreciated, but hints may be wasted on me, because at this point I think there's no hope of me getting anywhere here, so I pose this as a question for anyone to tackle for their own sake, rather than assisting me. Having said that a full solution to look at would be useful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are both solutions to the Neumann problem
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\nabla^2 \phi - \phi = \rho & \text{ in }  V\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} = f & \text{ on } \partial V
\end{cases} \ \ (*)
\end{align} 
then $\psi:=\phi_1-\phi_2$ is a solution to the problem 
\begin{align}
\begin{cases} 
\nabla^2 \psi - \psi = 0 & \text{ in }  V\\
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial n} = 0 & \text{ on } \partial V
\end{cases}. \ \ (**)
\end{align}

Now, multiply the PDE in $(**)$ by $\psi$  and perform integration by parts yields
\begin{align}
\int_V \psi\nabla^2 \psi - \psi^2\ dx = \int_{\partial V} \psi\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial n}\ dS-\int_V |\nabla\psi|^2+\psi^2\ dx = 0.
\end{align} 
Since $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial n}=0$, then it follows
\begin{align}
\int_V |\nabla \psi|^2+\psi^2\ dx = 0
\end{align}
which is only possible provided $\psi=\phi_1-\phi_2 \equiv 0$ on $V$. Hence $\psi_1\equiv \psi_2$ on $V$. Thus we have our uniqueness result.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be a useful answer to study